# what are difference between soem, ethercat_soem, rtnet and rtt_soem?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what are difference between above? as i saw soem and ethercat_soem have been part of ros packages. But i'm little confused which package to study, choole or use for my application. can anyone show me some of theri speciality and difference.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292388/what-are-difference-between-soem,-ethercat_soem,-rtnet-and-rtt_soem?/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2018-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Even though quite late, I'll give it a go...

- `soem`: this the original [SOEM library](https://github.com/OpenEtherCATsociety/SOEM), or if you are refering to the ROS package, the original SOEM library [wrapped as a ROS package](http://wiki.ros.org/soem)
- `ethercat_soem`: this seems to be the same, i.e. a [wrapper for soem](https://github.com/gt-ros-pkg/ethercat-soem), but quite outdated...
- `rtt_soem`: contains several packages, one was a wrapper for the original soem (`soem_core`), which has been replaced by the ROS `soem` wrapper above.

For rtnet, I'll quote the [webpage](http://www.rtnet.org/index.html):

> RTnet is an Open Soure hard real-time network protocol stack for Xenomai and RTAI (real-time Linux extensions).

In the end, IMHO, use `soem`, if you want to write a driver yourself. If you go for realtime, use `orocos`/ `rtt_soem` (if it works, no idea). Don't use `ethercat_soem`...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1